# How to hang up call in pjsip while its ringing

Tags: ios, voip, pjsip

I am working on iOS VOIP app using pjsip. I am able to make call and also able to hang up answered call but the problem is I can't hangup call when it is in its ringing state. So if anyone has any idea about it then please help.

Comment: incoming call or outgoing call? which one you need to hangup when ringing state.

Comment: @NandhaKumar outgoing call

Answer (score 3):

You can't call [pjsua_call_hangup](http://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/group__PJSUA__LIB__CALL.htm#gad716ae869d82756b1a45ad692de4db7a) on a call that hasn't been established state yet.  This is a sip part of the sip protocol.

What you do is send a response with a rejection status code.  So in pjsip you call [pjsua_call_answer](http://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/group__PJSUA__LIB__CALL.htm#ga6dd4a80bd96c319398e218bbffda5153) with a [status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SIP_response_codes) of something like 486 (busy here) or 603 (decline).  This will effectively "hangup" your ringing leg of the call.  You could also return a status code of 600 (busy everywhere) if you want all ringing legs to be released (assuming the sip proxy handles this status code correctly).